# Can you combine 2 of 3 brain wallet addresses to form a multi-address?

Tags: multi-signature, brain-wallet

Is there a way to use 2 of 3 brain wallet addresses to create a multi-signature address? How can this be done? I was hoping to do this with warp wallet if that is possible or not.

I'm assuming it would be like this:

- 3 people create their own brain wallet address via warp wallet tool.
- These 3 people put their address through a multi-sig tool?
- The tool spits out a 4th address that is the funding address?

FYI, I never did a multi-signature send before so I'm just assuming that's how it would work. If not, please correct my view of how it actually works if you were to use a brain wallet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with warp wallet, but this can be done via Armory. First generate the brainwallet addresses. Second import the private keys into 3 different wallets in Armory. Third, create a lockbox using those 3 addresses. Voila, you have a multisig address that can be sent to.

Comment: what is a lockbox? how can u do this without armory? dont i have to download the entire blockchain

Comment: you do have to download the blockchain to work with armory. Lockbox is a feature in Armory itself. You can also look into BitGo.